# How to save objects in TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, nsuserdefaults

I have a TabBar Application and I'm trying to set up a favorites tab.
I have managed to create a button and to send the favorited cell to the tab but right now if i add to favorites they are added correctly into the favorites tab but if i quit the app it doesn't save the favorites . How can i save the favorited cells in the favorite tab? would UserDefault do the best job? and if so how can it be done...

## This is how i set up my favorite button :

```
//create a new button
        let Favoritebutton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)
        //set image for button
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "EmptyHeart.png"), for: .normal)
        Favoritebutton.setImage(UIImage(named: "FilledHeart.png"), for: .selected)
        //add function for button
        Favoritebutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.button), for: .touchUpInside)
        //set frame
        Favoritebutton.frame = CGRect(x:0,y: 0,width: 35,height: 35)
        
        Favoritebutton.isSelected = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSaved")
        
        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: Favoritebutton)
        //assign button to navigationbar
        
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
        
    }


    @IBAction func button(sender: UIButton) {
        let newValue = !sender.isSelected
        sender.isSelected = newValue
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "isSaved")
        
        let tabItem = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![3]
        sel_val = tabItem?.badgeValue
        if(sel_val == nil){
            sel_val = "0"
        }
        let sel_num  = Int(sel_val!)
        
        let fav: NSMutableArray = []
        fav.add(barImage)
        fav.add(barName)
        fav.add(streetName)
        if sender.isSelected {
            tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! + 1)
            favorite.add(fav)
        } else {
            tabItem!.badgeValue = String(format: "%d", sel_num! - 1)
            favorite.remove(fav)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Newbie - I think you are not checking, second time when app open what is your favourite tab with your NSUserDefault.

Comment: Probably not ... How can i do that?

Comment: When you open app, You can check is there any favourite item is selected or not, if selected you can identify which is selected based on that you can show

Comment: Yes sure, But i am not much aware about swift.I will explain the flow you can go through.
- When app open in launch option you can check is there any selected item then fallow this *URL*( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325780/how-to-set-the-tab-bar-item-1-to-be-selected-by-default-in-iphone)